# Laravel Eloquent suddenly started echoing this error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Before thinking it's duplicate: Inside the `$request->input('birthdate')` variable, the date format is correct; for example is `'1979-02-11'`.

Even so, I get that error:

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '11/02/1979' for column 'birthdate' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `users` (`birthdate`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (11/02/1979, 26/06/2020, 26/06/2020))

Something about it has already been discussed in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/2212).

My application was doing fine. I guess after executing the `$ composer update` and then carrying on with the development when I was testing the register part, that error showed up.

I haven't found out why now inside the Laravel application the date formats are changed to 'mm/dd/yyyy'. In the request, the date format is as it should: 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

In the User.php model file I had originally:

```
    protected $dates=['birthdate'];
    
    /*My bad. I hadn't realized I probably added without noticing, the following piece of code*/
 /**
     * Date format
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dateFormat='d/m/Y';
```

And I have changed it to (according to [that same post](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/2212):

```
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    'birthdate'  => 'date:Y-m-d'
];
```

However, the error is still there even if I try with `$ php artisan tinker` and store the `$user->birthdate='1960-05-22';`.

```
Psy Shell v0.10.4 (PHP 7.4.5 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $user = new App\Models\User;
=> App\Models\User {#3358}
>>> $user->birthdate = '1960-05-22';
=> "1960-05-22"
>>> $user->save();
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '22/05/1960' for column 'birthdate' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `users` (`birthdate`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (22/05/1960, 26/06/2020, 26/06/2020))'
>>>
```

In the migration file I have declared the birth date column as follows:
`$table->date('birthdate')->nullable()->comment('Birthdate');`

What is going wrong now? Can anyone help?

**EDIT - Fixed**
My bad. I hadn't realized I probably added without noticing, the following piece of code:

```
//protected $dateFormat='d/m/Y';
protected $dateFormat='Y-m-d';
```

So I commented it out.

Comment: What's the `birthdate` type `date` or `datetime`?

Comment: Hi. In my migration file I have the following: `$table->date('birthdate')->nullable()->comment('Birthdate');`

Comment: Check `birthdate` column type in your database. And make sure is there `datetime` or `date`.

Comment: @GhanuBha Thank you. I have realized the problem was that somehow I added the following line `protected $dateFormat='d/m/Y';`  inside my `User.php` model.